# compactness of the subset in $l^{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $l^{2}$ be the space of all square-summable sequences. Let $a>0.$ Consider the following subset of $l^{2}$:
$$
S = \{\mathbf{x} = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, ): \sum_{i}x_{i} = a, \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\, x_{1} \geq x_{2} \geq \dots  \}.
$$

Is $S$ compact?

Comment: Any thoughts of your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $S$ is not strongly compact and not even weakly compact, because it is a hyperplane defined by an unbounded (not-closed, not everywhere defined) linear functional and hence not even weakly closed.

In more detail: without restriction of generality, let $a=1$. For any ${\mathbf{x}}$ in $S$, if there were any negative $x_i$ it would make the infinite series $\sum_{i}x_{i}$ diverge, taking the boundary condition into account. 
So the $x_i$ can only be nonnegative. Then $\sum_{i}x_{i}^2 \leq \sum_{i}x_{i} = 1$, hence $S$ is a subset of the unit ball in the space of square-summable sequences. The unit ball is weakly metrizable, so it suffices to find a Cauchy sequence $(\mathbf{x_i})$ without a limit in $S$.
Let the sequence $(\mathbf{x_i}) \subset S$ be

$$
\mathbf{x_1} = (1, 0, \dots )
$$
$$
\mathbf{x_2} = (1/2, 1/2, 0, \dots )
$$
$$
\mathbf{x_3} = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0, \dots )
$$

and so forth. The sequence converges strongly and weakly to the zero vector  which is not in $S$, so $S$ is not a closed subset of Hilbert space. Compact sets in Hausdorff spaces must be closed, so $S$ cannot be compact.

Comment: if we remove the condition $\sum_{i}x_{i}$ the $S$ is closed, isn't it?

Comment: If $\sum_{i}x_{i}=a$ is removed, correct, then $S$ is a closed subset of $l_2$. It is the intersection of (infinitely many) convex half-spaces defined by continuous linear forms. The forms look in coordinates like $(1,-1,0,...)$, $(0,1,-1,0,...)$ etc.

Comment: If I were writing this up I would just note the example you gave is a sequence in $S$ that converges to a point not in $S.$ Hence $S$ is not closed, and therefore not compact. Not sure if all the fancy stuff is necessary here.